# About convergent sequence $f_n \to f$ in $L^p(U)$ ( Convergence in norm, passage of limit under integral etc.. ; Evans's PDE )

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations, lebesgue-integral

Let $U$ be a bounded, connected, open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$.  Assume $1 \le  p \le \infty$ .Let $f_n \to f$ be a convergent sequence in $L^p(U)$.

My question is, then,

**Q.1.** $ \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \left\Vert f_n \right\Vert_p =\left\Vert f\right\Vert_p<\infty $?

I found assoicated post : [Convergence in Lp implies convergence in Lp norms finite](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2681652/convergence-in-lp-implies-convergence-in-lp-norms-finite). From the post, I think that the norm convergence is true for $1 \le p < \infty$. And, I also wonder whether this is true for $p=\infty$.

**Q.2.** For any test function $\phi\in C^{\infty}_c(U)$,

$$ \int_U f \phi dx = \lim_{n\to \infty}\int_U f_n \phi dx \tag{1}$$
? Let's define a functional $T_{\phi}$ on $L^p(U)$ by $T_{\phi}(f):=\int_U f \phi dx $ for all $f\in L^p(U)$. If $T$ is a 'bounded' linear functional on $L^p(U)$, then $T(f_n)$ converges to $T(f)$. But the boundness of $T_{\phi}$ ( including the case $p=\infty$ ) is true? Or is there any other route to show the $(1)$?

This question originates from following proof of the Poincare's inequality in the Evans's PDE Book ( p.275 ) :

[image]

[image]

Why the underlined statement is true?

Comment: Use Holder's inequality.

Comment: @PNDas : Abouta what question? Q.1.) ? or Q.2. )?..

Comment: For $p<\infty$: $\|T_{\phi} (f) \leq \|\phi\|_{\infty} \lim \sup_m \int |f_n|\le  \|\phi\|_{\infty} \lim \sup \|f_n\|_p (m(U))^{1/q}=\|\phi\|_{\infty} \|f\|_p (m(U))^{1/q}$ where $\frac 1 p +\frac 1  q=1$.  For $p=\infty$, $\|T_{\phi} (f)\|\le \|f\|_{\infty} \int |\phi|$.

Comment: Uhm.. still it seems that the symbol is little bit difficult to read :) e.g. , What is the definition of $m(U)$? The measure of $U$?

Comment: @geetha290krm : Can I aks more? In your argument for $p< \infty$, did you show the boundness of $T_{\phi}$? If so, to show boundness, it suffices to show that there exists an $M \ge 0 $ such that $|T_{\phi}(f) | \le M \cdot ||f||_{p}$ for all $f\in L^{p}(U)$. And an issue that makes me confused is, where does the notation $f_n$ in your argument in comment stick out from?

Comment: @geetha290krm : O.K. I reached to conclusion of my own. Anyway thanks for inspiration !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For the question 1)**, this is true by the inverse triangle inequality for norm ; $$\big|\,\|x\|-\|y\|\,\big|\le\|x-y\|.$$

**For the question 2)**, Note next theorem ( Hölder's Inequality )

> Theorem 1. Let $E$ be a measurable set, $1\le p < \infty$, and $q$ the conjugate of $p$. If $f$ belongs to $L^p(E)$ and $g$ belongs to $L^{q}(E)$, then their product $f\cdot g$ is integrable over $E$ and $$ \int_E|f\cdot g| \le \|f\|_{p} \cdot \|g\|_q.$$

Now as suggested in my original question, let me show that $T_{\phi}(f) :=\int_U f \phi dx $ ( $f \in L^{p}(U) $) is 'bounded' linear functional so that we are done.

To show the boundness of $T_{\phi}$, we need to show that there exists $M \ge 0$ such that
$$
|T_{\phi}(f)| := \bigg| \int_U f \phi dx\bigg| \le M \cdot \|f\|_p
$$ for all $f\in L^{p}(U)$.

First note that since $\phi \in C^{\infty}_c(U)$, $\phi \in L^{q}(U)$ for all $1 \le q \le \infty$.

Case 1) $1 \le p < \infty$ : Note that
$$\bigg| \int_U f \phi dx \bigg| \le \int_U |f\phi|dx \le \|f\|_p \cdot \|\phi\|_q =  \|\phi\|_q \cdot\|f\|_p ,$$
by the Hölder's Inequality

Case 2) $p=\infty$ : In this case, note that

$$ \bigg| \int_U f \phi dx \bigg| \le \int_U |f\phi|dx = \int_U |\phi f |dx \le \|\phi\|_1 \cdot \|f\|_{\infty} $$

also by the Hölder's Inequality.

So we are done. I would like to thank PNDas for his hint ( usage of the Hölder's Inequality ) through comment.